# Creating a relationship based on columns that are NOT the primary keys?

Tags: ms-access, database-design, foreign-keys, relationship

I have an access database which contains 23 tables. 
There is one Main table which houses all test equipment and contains 
columns headers 4-26. The other 22 tables are used to house the equipment related to a section (4-26). 
What I've been trying to do is setup relationships between each section table to the Main table's section column header. If there is an "X" within column 4 of the main table then add that column automatically to the section 4 table as well.

This is an overkill since the data is already in the main table. However, I wanted to reframe from having to read through the main table and separate equipment to its section in my applications run time.

Problems:

I've already tried setting up the relationships, however, my "relationship" type is "indeterminate" which I believe is because the tables are not referencing each others primary key column.

I created a section column in each of the section tables to denote a value 4-26. I then set that as my primary key, but primary keys (as far as i know) must be unique so that will not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you quoting "indeterminate" from?

Comment: Please edit your aswer to make clear exactly what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

Any list of columns of a table can form a foreign key in it. The referencing table and list of colums just has to reference a list of columns that forms a candidate key in the refereced table.

In SQL a PRIMARY KEY declares a UNIQUE NOT NULL column list. This is called a superkey. A superkey that contains no smaller superkey is a candidate key. Primary keys don't matter to integrity & normalization, candidate keys do. You can call some candidate key the primary key. (So an SQL PRIMARY KEY actually declares a superkey, what you might call a primary superkey, which might be a candidate key.)

A foreign key says that if you replace the column names in the referencing column list by their values in a row of the referencing table then you have to be able to make the same list of values by replacing the column names in the the referenced column list by their values in a row of the referenced table. If that's the case and there isn't already a chain of foreign keys from referencing table to the referenced tables that says the same thing then declare a foreign key. (The DBMS will use that fact for integrity and optimization.)

PS *Tables* (whether the values of base tables or query results) represent application relationships/associations. Certain tools, methods and presentations call foreign keys "relationships".

Answer (score 0):

Establish the primary key in the main table which will include the section values and use this in the section tables as both the primary key of that table and a foreign key back to the main table.

```
create table TestEquipment(
    ID      AutoNumber primary key,
    Section int not null,
    ..., -- other fields common to test equipment
    constraint CK_TestEquipmentSection( Section between 4 and 26 ),
    constraint UQ_TestEquipmentLink unique( ID, Section )
);
```

As ID will be unique all by itself, why create a unique constraint with ID and the section value? So we can refer to the combination with FKs in the section tables:

```
create table Section4(
    ID       int not null primary key,
    Section  int not null,
    ..., -- other fields for section 4 entries
    constraint CK_Section4 check( Section = 4 ),
    constraint FK_Section4TE foreign key( ID, Section )
        references TestEquipment( ID, Section )
};

create table Section5(
    ID       int not null primary key,
    Section  int not null,
    ..., -- other fields for section 5 entries
    constraint CK_Section5 check( Section = 5 ),
    constraint FK_Section5TE foreign key( ID, Section )
        references TestEquipment( ID, Section )
};
```

The other section tables will be similarly defined. When a piece of test equipment is entered, the key value is generated and the section number established by creating an entry in TestEquipment. A entry can then only be made in the section table with the matching section value. That is, if any entry is made in TestEquipment with an ID value of 1001 and Section value of 4, the only section table that can contain an entry with an ID value of 1001 will be the Section4 table. Any attempt to enter it into any of the other section tables will be rejected.

This is about the simplest way to do what it would appear you are trying to do.